# "Circular Dependencies" but works perfectly; How to fix it

Tags: python, callback, progress-bar, plotly-dash, circular-dependency

This program allows you to generate an activity (progress bar for example) during a long processing at the end of which the activity stops.

1. A first callback generates the activity with a `dcc.interval`.
2. The second callback controls the starting and stopping of the activity.
3. And the third simulates a long process of charging.

How to remove Circular Dependencies?
I tried to remove `Output("start", "n_clicks")` from the second callback because it seems to be causing the problem but then the messages "stop" and "start" are no longer triggered.

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import time

from dash import callback, callback_context, dcc, html, no_update
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Button("Start", id="start", n_clicks=0),
        dcc.Store(id="stop", storage_type="memory", data=""),
        dcc.Interval(id="interval", disabled=True, interval=500, n_intervals=0),
        html.Div(id="progress"),
    ]
)


@callback(
    Output("progress", "children"),
    Input("interval", "n_intervals"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def timer_callbak(interval):
    return interval


@callback(
    Output("start", "n_clicks"),
    Output("interval", "disabled"),
    Input("start", "n_clicks"),
    Input("stop", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def ctrl_callbak(start, s):
    ctx = callback_context
    if None is not ctx.triggered:
        tid = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

        if "start" == tid and start:
            print("start")
            return no_update, False

        elif "stop" == tid:
            print("stop")
            return no_update, True

        else:
            raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate


@callback(
    Output("stop", "data"),
    Input("start", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def main_callbak(click):
    for i in range(10):
        print("Hello", i)
        time.sleep(1)
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! In this particular case instead of `ctrl_callbak` you could use two separate and much simpler callbacks:

```py
@callback(
    Output("interval", "disabled", allow_duplicate=True),
    Input("stop", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def on_stop_data_ready(_):
    print("stop")
    return True


@callback(
    Output("interval", "disabled", allow_duplicate=True),
    Input("start", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def on_start_button_click(_):
    print("start")
    return False
```

You may also want to read about [loading states](https://dash.plotly.com/loading-states) and `Loading` component in Dash:

> Dash uses this prop in the `Loading` component to display spinners if a component is loading. This means you can use the `Loading` component to wrap other components that you want to display a loading spinner for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You have make my code working without circular dependencies. I did not know  that it was possible to duplicate an Output and after brosing the doc I saw that it possible since the 2.9 dash version. Greet news! Thants again for your help.

Comment: @YaOo pleased to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: How could I do that ?

Comment: There is a "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons. [docs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: I'm really sorry Dimitry, but I don't see a "checkmark" button on my page. I don't know how to do what you're asking me.